# Not able to create new android project in android

Tags: android, eclipse

eclipse is working fine with importing a project which already exist. But i am facing problem while am creating a new project in the android. [image: see the error]

And then am trying to change the path in the properties of the project which i have created then it is showing some kind of error and screen shot of it is [image: screen shot of properties of project]

Can any one help me in this.

Comment: open windows >> Show View >> console

Comment: is there any message are shown in console?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your d: drive is an actual hard drive you have the android-sdk in, and not some DVD/CD drive you tried installing the android-sdk from.

You should click on your new android project folder, right-click and click on "close unrelated projects", then the right files will get generated correctly (re-initiate a manual rebuild if you have to).

The problem was that Eclipse was trying to rebuild all the projects you had in your workspace, a number of which already contained errors in them. Not only those other projects were clogging up your error log, but when an error is detected by the packager/builder, the building process gets stopped entirely.

Now just in case this wasn't your only problem, do Help > Check updates
After that, click on the menu Window > AVD Manager and something
and make sure that you have the latest SDKs and AVD updates already installed.

Also be aware that Pulsar is not the recommended version of Eclipse for doing Android development, although this probably wasn't what was causing your problem.